# Adding GMP to own library

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries, gmp

How to add GMP to my static library?

In MyLib.h I have

```
#include<gmp.h>
#include<gmpxx.h>
```

and some functions like:

```
void fun(mpz_t &a, mpz_t b){
     mpz_add(a,a,b);
}
```

My static library I have created by

```
gcc -std-c++11 -c mbib.c -o mbib.o
ar  rcs libmbib.a      mbib.o
```

I have linked mbib.o and when i dont use functions from there it works. But when I'm trying to use any of them i have:

```
/home/MBIB/libmbib.a(mbib.o):-1: In function `__gmp_binary_plus::eval(__mpz_struct*, __mpz_struct const*, __mpz_struct const*)': 
mbib.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `__gmpz_add'
/home/MBIB/libmbib.a(mbib.o):-1: In function `__gmp_binary_multiplies::eval(__mpz_struct*, __mpz_struct const*, long)':
mbib.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `__gmpz_mul_si'
```

I have tried add

```
LIBS += -L[path] -lgmp -lgmpxx
```

but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: You can't.

You can't because you don't "link" with other libraries when you create a static library, a static library is nothing more than an archive collecting object files, you don't actually use a linker to create a static library. The command `ar` and the filename suffix `.a` all stands for "archive".

If you have a static library that depends on another static library, then you need to build with the other library as well for the final executable (or dynamic library).

Comment: To be fair, you can. As you say, the .a is just an archive, and you can take 2 archives and merge them into one...